# Equatiomatic:Error in vapply(names(pred_level), function(x) { : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0

Tags: r

I am running a mixed model:

```
assign(
  paste("M_FACTOR_", h, sep = ""),
  lmerTest::lmer(
    LogT ~ 1 + as.factor(Monthly) * gender + (as.factor(Monthly) | ID),
    data = plot_data,
    REML = TRUE,
    control = lmerControl(optimizer = 'optimx', optCtrl = list(method = 'nlminb'))
  )
) # apply model (Monthly as factor)
```

```
eq_fac <- equatiomatic::extract_eq(get(eval(paste("M_FACTOR_", h, sep = ""))), 
                                   wrap = TRUE)
```

Throws the following error which I do not manage to debug.

> Error in vapply(names(pred_level), function(x) { :
> values must be length 1,
> but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0`

Is it because I use Monthly as factor?

Comment: Hi Cdo, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: Try creating a new variable (`plot_data$fMonthly <- factor(plot_data$Monthly)`), use it in your model instead of `as.factor(Monthly)`, and see if that resolves the problem?

Comment: @BenBolker: When converting the variable Monthly to factor before using it in the lmer-function it did indeed solve the problem! 

I can hereby confirm that you should not use as.factor(x) in the lmer if you want to extract the equation with equatiomatic. Thank you so much. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equatiomatic could extract the function when the factor was assigned outside of the lmer function.

```
plot_data$Monthly<-as.factor(plot_data$Monthly) #to ensure that equatiomatic can extract the equation

assign(paste("M_FACTOR_", h, sep=""), lmerTest::lmer(LogT ~1+Monthly*gender + (Monthly|ID), data=plot_data, 
                                                REML = TRUE,control = lmerControl(optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb')))) # apply model (Monthly as factor)
eq_fac<-equatiomatic::extract_eq(get(eval(paste("M_FACTOR_", h, sep=""))), wrap=TRUE)
```